# python split a string with special charcter

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, special-characters

I need to split a string that I receive like that :

```
my_string = "\data\details\350.23.43.txt"
```

when I use `my_string.replace ("\\", "/")`

it returns : /data/detailsè.23.43.txt

It's considering the `\350` in my string as a special character `'è'`

Comment: you need to split or to replace?

Comment: I need to split; but I tried to replace it first
but my need is to split

Comment: which character are you trying to split by - `\\`?

Comment: If you receive it, the characters should probably be good, but if you specify it as above then yes the '\350' will be replaced by 'è' in the string itself. Where does the string come from?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko yes

Comment: The problem is with your string literal, not with what you subsequently do with that literal. `my_string` as defined above simply isn't the string that you think it is. For example, `print(my_string)` prints `\data\detailsè.23.43.txt`

Comment: so no workaround for that ?

Comment: The "workaround" is to create the string properly in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit after your comment:
Try

```
my_string = r"\data\details\350.23.43.txt"
```

---

That happens because \ooo is interpreted as a character with octal value as described in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

I guess the only way is to escape the \ as in:

```
my_string = "\data\details\\350.23.43.txt"
```

Then you can do stuff like:

```
my_string.split("\\")
```

Where do you get the string from? Is there a way to influence that?

And this looks like a path. It would be better to use

```
os.path.join("data", "details", "350.23.43.txt")
```

to create paths independently of the operating system.

Comment: the problem is that I'm receiving it like that I can't modify it

Comment: Try adding an r before your string as in my edit above.

Comment: If you "are receiving it like that", then the string **actually does contain** a `è` character, and the problem must be fixed in the sender.

Answer (score 1):

`\` in string literals are treated as escaping chars. That is why `s1 = "line\nsecond line"` creates a string with two lines. That is also why you use `"\\"` in `my_string.replace ("\\", "/")`.

So to fix your problem, if you're using a string literal `my string = "\data\details\350.23.43.txt"` you should instead use `"\\data\\details\\350.23.43.txt"` to make sure your `\` are properly escaped. Alternatively, you can use a raw string `my string = r"\data\details\350.23.43.txt"` by prepending `r` to the quote. That way nothing gets escaped (so `r"\n"` would be a 2 char string with `\` and `n` instead of just a single new line char)